# Is it possible to pass a org.teleal.cling.model.meta.Device class to another Activity in Android

Tags: android, upnp

I am using the cling api to create a upnp endpoint under Android.
I don't know how to pass a device that i ve found in one Activity to another.
Is this possible?

I ve tried using a sychronised funciton in a MyApplication class(which extends Application).
How ever, when i tried to get or set the device it always caused a ClassCastException

Thank you!

Comment: is the class "Device" implementing the serialisable interface? if yes, you could try to pass the object via a serialized bundle to the next activity

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `UDN` string and use it in other activity. Service interface can be used to list all devices and `UDN` to find device you need.

```
Device device = upnpService.getRegistry().getDevice(myDeviceUDN, true);
```